# Don't compress '0px' in '0' with LESS/CSS minificator

Tags: css, less, flexbox, grunt-contrib-less

I would like to compress my LESS file where I use the new flexbox display like that :

```
flex: 1 1 0px;
```

I use [grunt-contrib-less](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-contrib-less) with the compress option active and the result is:

```
flex: 1 1 0;
```

It's work fine for Chrome and FF, but don't work in IE 11 when there is no 'px' after the 0.

Do you know a way to don't remove the 'px' or is it just a bug with my code and IE?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could [escape the value](http://lesscss.org/functions/#string-functions):

```
element {
  flex: ~"1 1 0px";
}
```

Since you are trying to escape a variable, you would use:

```
element {
  flex: ~"@{grow} @{shrink} @{basis}";
}
```

Comment: I try to escape, but in fact I have 3 variables `flex: @grow @shrink @basis;`, so I can't escape that way.